# execute caspol from within vbscript

Tags: vbscript, wsh, caspol

I'd like to call caspol from within a script inside a custom action in
an msi (setup project). I'd prefer a standard msi to ClickOnce,
because with a standard msi I can install drivers & associate
filetypes with our application whereas with ClickOnce I can't.

When I execute the caspol command from the command line it succeeds,
but from within vbscript it always fails with the error "Fehler:
Unbekannte Mitgliedschaftsbedingung - -url.." - which translates as
"Error: Unknown membership condition: -url". To further clarify: A
copy & paste of the generated command works fine on the command line
directly on the local drive of a virgin virtual machine, as local
administrator, as part of a workgroup.

I have two ideas:
1. I'm no vbscript king, so maybe I've missed quotes or made some
other sort of syntax error.
2. Caspol recognises that I'm running it from within a script and
halts with an intentionally nonsensical error.

Personally, I believe it's just a dumb syntax error.

Here's my script:

```
set sh = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

dim command
dim location
dim retVal

location = fso.GetFile(Wscript.ScriptFullName).ParentFolder

'%windir%\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe -pp off -m -addgroup 1 –url file://COMPUTER/SHARE/* FullTrust -name sbw2
command = fso.GetSpecialFolder(0) & "\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe -pp off -m -ag 1 –url file://"
for each s in Split(location, "\")
        if Len(s) > 0 then
                command = command & s & "/"
        end if
next
command = command & "* FullTrust -name sbw2"

'DEBUG
'command = fso.GetSpecialFolder(0) & "\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe -m -ag 1 –url file://mjlaptop/sbw2/* FullTrust"
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine VbClrf
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine command
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine VbClrf

Set output = sh.Exec(command)

dim text
while Not output.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
        text = text & output.StdOut.Read(1)
Wend
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine text
```

Thanks in advance,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change url formatting of url in command to \\mjlaptop\sbw2*
for some reason, formatted as "file://..." won't work. With or without quotes.

This uid (yossarian) belongs to me (Matt Jacobsen) too. I'd had to use the above as claimid was down for maintennance.

Comment: I'm accepting my own answer here. To clarify, I am both Cpt. Yossarian and Matt Jacobsen. Feel free to complain if you think it's necessary.

Comment: Convenient. Maybe you deserve an up-vote as well for finding out?

Answer (score 0):

No that's not it. Even with 
    command = command & """" 
at the end of all that string concatenation.

Comment: The code answer provided above won't even compile. Nice idea to take my simple suggestion that I've missed a quote and, heh, quote it back to me, but if you're gonna do that you have to be certain it's going to run without throwing a simple syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Copy & pasted from your answer into my code:

```
"C:\WINDOWS\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe -pp off -m -ag 1 -url "file://mjlaptop/sbw2/*" FullTrust -name sbw2

\\mjlaptop\sbw2\setpolicy.vbs(32, 1) WshShell.Exec: Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
```

It's missing a quote. And now, adding a closing quotation mark, as I guess you intended:

```
"C:\WINDOWS\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe" -pp off -m -ag 1 -url "file://mjlaptop/sbw2/*" FullTrust -name sbw2

Microsoft (R) .NET Framework CasPol 2.0.50727.42
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Fehler: Unbekannte Mitgliedschaftsbedingung - -url..
```

That's the error as given in my original post. You're right: the command is valid. That the command is valid isn't the problem. I can copy and paste the bloody echo into a command window and it'll execute successfully. I can stick as many quotes in there as you like, and I reckon it'll still complain about the "unknown membership condition" though.

I'll try to make my replies in comments.

Comment: Tomalak, you were on the right track. I haven't tried your syntax though since I found the solution myself.

Comment: ...yep! caspol must accept both formats of the "url", but for some reason the only one to work through vbs is the "network share" form. I've had some issues with this form of url in conjunction with caspol before at a customer site though.

Answer (score 0):

"C:\WINDOWS\microsoft.net\framework\v\caspol" -pp off -m -ag 1 -url "file://mjlaptop/sbw2/*" FullTrust -name sbw2

Microsoft (R) .NET Framework CasPol 2.0.50727.42
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Fehler: Unbekannte Mitgliedschaftsbedingung - -url..

using the v instead of the whole file name allows the code to search caspol in every version folder.