# Registration during Setup/Install packages

Tags: .net, setup-deployment

Is it possible to register a .NET component during the installation of a VB6 app?

Is it also possible to grant security (eg. via CAPSOL) as part of an installation package?

Will InnoSetup do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corresponds to http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection you can use *StrongAssemblyName* with the flag *gacinstall* in the **[Files]** section (see also [Adding assemblies to the GAC from Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61699/adding-assemblies-to-the-gac-from-inno-setup) and http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Applications/Q_25148021.html). You should do this only is assembly which you install a strong type assembly. Other .NET assembly which hat a interop part for usage from COM/VB can be installed like other DLLs or COM-dlls.

With possibility to implement custom functionality (see http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?custom) you can run any exe during the setup and so make some work which is not exist out-of-the-box.

With respect of *permission* entry in **[Dirs]** section (see http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=dirssection) you can set permission on all file components which you install. The same *permission* entry in **[Regisry]** section (see http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection) allow you to set permission in registry.

**UPDATED:** If you do need use caspol.exe (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=131738) you can use custom functionality (see http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?custom) to start this or look at [execute caspol from within vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295209/execute-caspol-from-within-vbscript) for discussion about the usage of caspol.exe. An example for usage caspol.exe in [Run] section you can find in http://zerosandtheone.com/blogs/vb/archive/2008/06/23/vb-net-install-your-app-and-the-net-framework-using-inno-setup.aspx (search on the page for "v2.0.50727\CasPol.exe")

Answer (score 0):

All depends what sort of setup app you use - the more advanced MSI creators like Wise have configuration options for .NET assemblies. If you don't have something like that then you'll have to fire off command-lines for regasm to register the .net component and caspol to configure security.